# debian port 80 does not accept remote connections

Tags: node.js, http, debian, remote-access, iptables

I have a **Node.js** express website that was listening on port `9000`, the thing which was fine until I changed the port to `80`, now it accepts only connection from local:

```
wget http://127.0.0.1/ -O -
curl 127.0.0.1:80
```

Locally it's working fine and they return the html page. But it does not accept remote connections from browser, either using the external IP address or the domain name.

```
# iptables

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `netstat -anpt`?

Comment: please show us the (relevant) config of your `Node.js` instance, where you configure the port: it's easy to configure a server that only accepts connections on a speficic interface (e.g. `lo`)

Comment: thank you guys for your interest in helping me, i have figured it out, the port forwarding rules was redirecting connections from port 80 to another port

Answer (score 0):

Well, i have figured the issue, it was my iptables rules forwarding remote connections from outside to another port.